# Email not sending in contact form

Tags: html, xampp, php

i have a contact page for my php/html website and i am trying to send an html email in php using the mail function but the email never goes through i don't get any errors.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
        $required = array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Subject', 'Message');

        if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
            {
                foreach ( $required as $formfield )
                {
                    if (empty($_POST[$formfield]))
                    {
                        header("Location: contact.html");
                        die();
                    }
                }

                $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
                $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
                $Email = $_POST['Email'];
                $Subject = $_POST['Subject'];
                $Message = $_POST['Message'];

                $To = "edjoks3000@rocketmail.com"; 
                $From = $Email;           

                //begin of HTML message
                $Message = <<<EOF
                    <html>
                      <body bgcolor="#DCEEFC">

                    $Message

                      </body>
                    </html>     
EOF;

                $Headers  = "From: $From\r\n";
                $Headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

                // Sending the mail
                mail($To, $Subject, $Message, $Headers);
            }


    ?>
```

I've been trying for a while now and have not been able to do this and i do not want to use mail plugins like 'swift' or 'phpmailer' since i get issues with them when i upload to the server.

Answer (score 0):

semicolon missing after `EOF`  change to `EOF;`

Comment: Okay i did that and i read somewhere that the 'eof' should be the first thing on the line not preceeded by any tabs or space so i tried that to and got rid of the error but ow the mail just doesn't come through.